# How to install ggplot2 in R version 3.2.1 for Mac

Tags: r, ggplot2, installation, package, osx-mountain-lion

I just downloaded new Mac versions of R and Rstudio, but am getting the following error message when I try to install ggplot2 through the Rstudio interface. Is there an alternative approach?

```
> install.packages("ggplot2")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ggplot2’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)
Installing package into ‘/Users/tom.glaser/Library/R/3.2/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ggplot2’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/3.2
Warning message:
package ‘ggplot2’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)
```

My session info is:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.1
```

I don't know if it's significant, but I'm having similar problems with many other packages I've tried, including psych and Hmisc. I was able to install dplyr (version 0.4.2). I tried going back to an earlier version of R, but the Mac versions I found were too old:
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/old/index-old.html

Comment: did you try a different mirror on Cran?

Comment: @RichardErickson my CRAN mirror is specified as Global (CDN) - RStudio. Can you recommend an alternative?

Comment: @user3614783 Just try any other mirror. I know every now and then I get issues with the RStudio mirror so just try something else and see if it works.

Comment: @Dason thanks! Different mirror did the trick.

Comment: If a different mirror worked for you, write up your answer and mark it as the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem by going into Rstudio, and clicking on Tools and then Options. I then selected Packages from the pop-up box. This popped up the Package Installation screen, where I clicked on "Change" next to CRAN mirror, and then selected the mirror called USA (CA 1) - University of California, Berkeley.

Answer (score 1):

I got to this problem also, and finally solved it by uncheck the "Use secure download method for HTTP" option in Tools->Global Options->Packages.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works, try this:

1. ggplot2 installation on MAC by AMRIT DHILLON

   (a) Open https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html and download ggplot2 (tzg) file for MAC [DIRECT LINK TO DOWNLOAD IS HERE]: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.3/ggplot2_2.2.0.tgz

   (b) Open ggplot2.tgz file with Archive Utility and it will be extracted in a Folder.

   (c) Copy ggplot2 Folder.

   (d) While pressing Option key, Select Go from Finder's Menu, and select and open Library ( Hidden file, only become visible when you select GO while holding Option Key).

   (e) From Library go to a Library folder of R:  Library > R > 3.3 > Library  (Paste ggplot2 folder here)

   (f) Restart R and you are good to go.

Regards,
Amrit Dhillon

Answer (score 0):

I also solved the issue by instead of typing it in the script. I went to > tools >install packages > ggplots2 > install. I don't know why that was any different but it installed.